# Android: Open files with a custom extension and only these files

Tags: android, gmail, mime-types, file-extension, intentfilter

I want to open files with the extension .bslvl in my app. I used the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data
      host="*"
      android:mimeType="*/*"
      android:pathPattern=".*\\.bslvl"
      android:scheme="file" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is that the Path-Pattern doesn't work. Every file with an unknown extension get's opened by my app now automatically. (For example .cfg .rdroid .rudi files)

If I change things in the intent-filter .bslvl files are not viewed with my app.

The same problem is with email attachments. I used an other intent-filter, since gmail couldn't find my app as viewer for .bslvl files, where I only changed the mimeType to

```
android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
```

However, now gmail tries to view every file with an unknown ext. with my app.

What have I done wrong?

Other solutions here on stackoverflow haven't solved my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix your issue, but I believe it should be "android:host" instead of "host"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified an android:host attribute.

According to the [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) docs...

> These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.

It looks like you tried to provide a host, but you forgot to qualify your host attribute with the android namespace.